# Facebook Wordpress Plugin

Tags: wordpress, facebook-like

I recently installed the official Facebook plugin to my WordPress site http://www.napsbitmesra.com  but the 'like' and 'send' buttons are not working.  I am unable to figure out why.

Am getting "The page at URL could not be reached" when i click on send and the 'Like' button is working but the like counter doesn't increment nor does the page show up on my timeline.

Comment: browser compatibility issues . try enabling javascript. hope it helps

Comment: Am getting "The page at URL could not be reached" when i click on send and the 'Like' button is working but the like counter doesn't increment nor does the page show up on my timeline.

Comment: Hi its working fine from my end. Check it once again.

Comment: Have you tried clearing your cache?  Tried from other machines?

Comment: if you want plugin there are more plugins like http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/facebookall/

Answer (score 2):

Instead of plugin use a script from Facebook developer.
Go to [this link](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) and fill your Facebook page URL

This will 100% works...